# Orchard CMS Speed Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm setting up an Orchard CMS site and noticing that it is incredibly slow.
It is running on a VPS that hosts a couple of other MVC based websites which all run fine, so the server doesn't appear to be the issue.

I've read that renaming the **Sample.Host.Config** file to **Host.Config** should fix the issue. Which it seems to do for a few hours, until randomly I then get the following error and the site no longer works.

```
The type 'Orchard.Environment.Configuration.AzureBlobTenantManager' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly".
```

I've tried installing the **Cache** module which hasn't made any difference.

Has anyone else experienced slowness with Orchard CMS? This is a brand new installation with no extra modules and no content... I'm stumped!

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can try:

- As you did, renaming the config file. You need to make sure you are running a prebuilt version.
- Installing the Cache module, as you did. This is going to be bundled into Core, it is essential.
- Installing the SysCache module to cache database calls
- Install the Warmup Module which saves static versions of your pages to serve to the user
- Turn off debug flag in Web.config (just in case... ^_^)
- Use SQL Server for the speeeeeed
- Make sure you have selected the same region for database etc.

To the specific error you are receiving, I also had that error a while back but this was due to my package not being fully built. So why yours would run for a while then break is a mystery... Did you maybe install some modules or something?

Comment: Hi Hazza, thanks for your response. Could you elaborate on using a "prebuilt version"?

Comment: @TomGlenn to get a "prebuilt" version, open a VS command prompt, head  to the base folder of the solution (with the build.bat) file, and type build Precompiled - it should create a release version in /build/Precompiled for you to use

Answer (score 1):

Enable the SysCache module in the "Performance" section of Modules

Answer (score 0):

I would also disable the dynamic module loader, stated here towards the middle of the page: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation