# Why Orchard on Azure Website Standard Small instance builds so long?

Tags: azure, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, kudu

I'm building Orchard 1.6 with a bunch of modules (with my module included). 56 modules total. And it has been building it for almost 3 hours on Azure Website Standard Small Instance (1 core, 1,75 MB memory).

And it took 2,54 GB of file system storage.

I build it by linking Azure to Bitbucket repository. In the repository there is all Orchard source code with modules, etc.

In my `.deployment` file:

```
[config]
project= src\Orchard.web\Orchard.Web.csproj
command = build.cmd fastbuild
```

Why it takes so long?

UPDATE.
It took 5h:

```
9:09:51 PM Updating submodules.  
9:09:51 PM Preparing deployment for commit id 'XXXXXXXXXX'.   
9:09:51 PM Running custom deployment command... 
9:09:51 PM Running deployment command...View Log  
2:20:27 AM Deployment successful.
```

(It looks like the Orchard.proj did all testings (specflow, unit test). Probably it didn't take `fastbuild` parameter. Need to check it. )

And it took 2,61GB. It is annoying as I hoped to deploy to Shared instance (<1GB). Need to check azure storage variant now.

Thank you

Comment: Can check this post for some tips for speeding it up. And you want to deploy a prebuilt version of the code. So run the click to build command prompt. Then you are not deploying all the source files etc.

Comment: @Hazza, I'm trying now to deploy prebuilt `src\orchard.web` as website (with `.deployment` targeted to it). Thank you

Comment: And it worked. Thinking now how to make db deployment for stage and production on azure...

Comment: Why would you build on Azure, and on a website small instance in addition? This will cost you a fortune for no benefit. Build precompiled on your dev machine and deploy the results.

Comment: Thank you. That looks the best chose so far. Though the repository should be roomy.

Answer (score 1):

Totally failed to actually write the link in the comment. Here are some tips for speeding up your site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16240746/1037489 And of course, the prebuilt version is the one to use, should be much faster. Click-to-build command is your friend. Make sure you have a source enlistment to be able to use it.